# Can I start my app from an event in the Android phone calendar created with my app?

Tags: android, android-calendar

I am developing an app in Android targeting versions >= 4.0 
(I am able to use the Calendar API)

In my app I receive array of events from a server and I cache them locally using SQLite. 
I had a requirement for this events to also appear in the native phone calendar. 
I managed to have my app insert events in the native phone calendar using the Calendar API.
Now, I have another requirement to be able to start my app (event details screen) when an event created using my app is clicked from the native phone calendar.

My question is, am I able to achieve this in Android and if so, then how? Is there something like a pending intent  I can specify when inserting events in the calendar from my app ?

Comment: Did my answer solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `AlarmManager` to do that, I used did diffrently but it can be used also for this task. just register an alarm to the time you want yourprogram to be activated and when the `BroadcastReciver` class get the `onRecieve` start your application.
maybe there are other simpler ways to do that. but I dont know them.
you can see: [Alarm Manager Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example)
for more details regarding `AlarmManager`